# New feed items not showing in Google Reader

Tags: wordpress, rss, google-reader

There is a [blog](http://kyara.readmyblog.net), powered by Wordpress, which has valid RSS feed (opens up fine in Safari), but doesn't show new posts in Google Reader. In fact, the latest article from Google Reader is from Jul 21, 2010, while the latest article on the blog dates to Aug 19, 2010.

What should I do about the RSS feed (escape characters? modify XML or what?) for it to work on Google Reader?

This is a [reopened question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128313/google-reader-doesnt-update-my-feed-closed), because the original question I found was migrated to superuser, then closed there because it is best fitted on stackoverflow, so no solution was ever provided, and no chance was given to do so. **Please give it a chance to get answered.**

**Update:**
Google Reader pulls new articles, in groups of 10, and not the latest. For example if 12 (or 13, or 11) new articles are not shown in Google Reader, when the next one is added, the oldest 10 (exactly 10) of these articles appear on Google Reader, and the date shown in Google Reader is equal for each article, as if all 10 were published in the same second - the second they appeared on Google Reader. This problem doesn't manifest itself in other aggregators that I've tried.

**Update 2:**
Articles started showing up regularly, so the problem is solved, temporarily. Why did it happen I don't know, maybe it's because more readers subscribed (for testing purposes), or it's because of the PubSubHubBub plugin that I've added recently. Until it becomes clear, and for 3 more days, this question remains open.

Comment: It's not clear whether you are the *user* of this feed, or the *author/developer*, this could explain why your question got bounced around.

Comment: That was not my question, but it's the one I've found when searching before opening a new question. The QUESTION I asked is clear, I want to know how to edit the RSS feed, or what can I change in the Wordpress Engine, or what plugins to install, etc, so that it would work properly. I am in the role of the developer here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just added the [blog](http://kyara.readmyblog.net/) to my Google Reader and had a bit of a play. I noticed the same behaviour you observed where I was missing the 5 most recent posts and a bunch of about 10 of them all had the same date:

[image]

After doing a bit of a search on the web, I found [this post](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/01/google-reader-shows-published-date.html) which explains how you can actually view the Published date via a tooltip on the right-hand side:

[image]

Then once I click the "Refresh" button from Google Reader at the top, the new posts showed up:

[image]

I believe that high volume blogs that are on the Google spiders' radar would be indexed every few hours and therefore all posts would have their Received date very close to the Published date so nobody notices/cares that it is actually displaying the Recevied date.

For low volume blogs however, it seems the cache is updated much less frequently. Google has some tips to try to get it to update - [Feed not updating in Reader](http://www.google.com/support/reader/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=97875).  Maybe my subscription to the blog updated the cache, but as the spider has a delay I didn't see the updates till pressing "Refresh". Or maybe the act of pressing the "Refresh" button triggered it to look for new posts immediately.

Lastly I subscribed the blog to my wife's Google Reader account and this time the 5 latest posts came up straight away with matching Received times which translated back to about the time when I pressed the "Refresh" button (or maybe it was when I added the feed).

I feel your pain - I agree that it all seems a bit cumbersome for a low volume RSS feed ...

Comment: This is a partially correct answer. It does answer a part of the question, but it remains unclear, what is the factor that determines the frequency of checking. Thank you. I will write more details as soon as they become available.

Answer (score 0):

You may also check with the blog author / hosting company and see if they have turned down the Google indexing rate.  Google can create high volumes of traffic on a site.  Turning down the indexing rate (crawl rate) will help with that but it b0rks Google Reader.

As other posters have mentioned, it could also be a factor of low popularity / low page rank / something else causing Googlebot to fail to crawl the blog frequently enough.

Google Reader display is dependent on Google crawling the blog to pick up the latest content. Realistically, you'll want a client side pull of the RSS feed to get the latest data so you aren't dependent on Google crawling the website.  Outlook 2010, Firefox, many others exist.  The client side software will directly pull the updated RSS feed from the blog, capturing the posts as they are published to the RSS feed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses, I too have come up with some possible solutions (thanks to you).

I don't know whether It's something I did, or independent of that, but as from yesterday (when you answered to this question), feeds started showing up normally.

Maybe it is due to the fact that thanks to you the blog got more subscribers on Google Reader and the Update Rate bounced (just like @Bermo suggested).

Or, maybe the introduction of the PubSubHubBub plugin changed something. But it's rather the first variant (number of subscribers). Though it is still a mystery why other extremely unpopular blogs give me regular articles in Google Reader.

For now I will only upvote good answers, until everything becomes clear (can't really determine the exact cause) or until the last day of this bounty.